# Serilog.Extras.AppSettings and complex objects

Tags: c#, appsettings, serilog

I'm using the Serilog.Extras.AppSetting package, to configure Serilog. I'm attempting to use the Email sink (Serilog.Sinks.Email), but I can't figure out how to configure the network credentials property via an AppSetting.

```
    <add key="serilog:using" value="Serilog.Sinks.Email" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Email.mailServer" value="localhost" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Email.fromEmail" value="test@google.com" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Email.toEmail" value="test@google.com" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Email.restrictedToMinimumLevel " value="Error" />

<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.networkCredential" value="???" />
```

How can I specify/represent an *NetworkCredential* object using AppSettings? Is it even possible, or is this a limitation of the AppSetting approach to configuration in Serilog?

Comment: I had this working as you suggest with     <add key="serilog:write-to:Email.credentials" value='{"Username":"bdamore@xxxxx.com", "Password":"xxxxxx"}' /> but in my flailing I messed it up again. If I get it working once more, I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a nice way to do this, unfortunately.

Where this has popped up in the past we've sometimes added overloads with simple parameters - raising a bug or PR to that effect would be welcome.

Otherwise, reading the values out of `AppSettings` manually and configuring the sink in code is the best bet.

Comment: Is it still the case?

Comment: Yes, though a PR adding a username/password overload would very likely be included. Cheers!

Comment: Was this added yet? I would need this, too.

Answer (score 0):

Does Serilog pick up settings from the [`<mailSettings>` element in your app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx)? If not, this would make a good PR ;)